# Finding the function from the derivative

Tags: integration

The derivative, f'(x), for a function f(x) is given by: $$ f'(x)=x^.5-3x^2 +1,  x >-1$$
Find the function f(x).

If I am not wrong, the answer should be the integrated derivative: $$ f(x)=\frac{x^{1.5}}{1.5} - x^3 + x + c$$
Can someone confirm or correct me on this? I do not have access to the answer and the marker has marked this wrong. This is part (a) of the question.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you are using the same letter $f$ for both the derivative (the question) and the function (the answer) this looks right. I suggest you edit the question to tell us the exact wording of what you were asked.

Comment: exact wording added, thanks

Comment: I think your only recourse is a polite question to the marker. You can say (politely) that you asked several sources to check your work before contacting him.

Comment: You say it's part of a question. What's the rest of it?

Comment: I may have to. thanks!

Comment: Andrew, that is all of the information given for part (a) of the question. Part (b) should not be required to solve part (a) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check consider

$$f(x)=\frac{x^{1.5}}{1.5} - x^3 + x + c$$

and compute

$$f'(x)=x^{.5} - 3x^2 + 1$$

that's always the best and maybe unique method to check.

Comment: I assume from the question that the OP did this. His real question is "why was this not accepted?" You haven't given him an answer (perhaps because there is no good answer).

Comment: thank you. working backwards, it seems correct, so i may have to take this up with the marker

Comment: @RudraMutalik Check also the format for the answer or it is given as choice?

Comment: @EthanBolker as you can see the suggestion was not so bad, sometimes what is obvious for us is not so obviuos for who is learning the subject. I alway try to put myself in this position because I know that, not always but often, these kind of basic suggestion are very useful.